# Unable to export path map with next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, next.js, antd

I am trying to use ant design with my next js project. I am able to design and develop everything seamlessly but I have problems deploying my code coz I am unable to export.
Following is the script I am trying to execute:-

```
/* eslint-disable */
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')

// fix: prevents error when .css files are required by node
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.css'] = file => {}
}

module.exports = withCss(),{
    exportPathMap: function () {
      return {
        '/': { page: '/' },
        '/about': { page: '/about' },
        '/abc': { page: '/abc'},
        '/other': { page: '/other'},
        '/there': { page: '/there'},
        '/sample':{page:'/sample'},
        '/details':{page:'/details'}
      }
    }
  }
```

If I run npm run next or npm run next build everything works fine but if I run npm run export I get No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages" and a SyntaxError: Unexpected token {.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with next.js but it does seems like syntax error to use `,` outside a function call, or an array or something..

Comment: @MoshFeu thank you for the prompt response. What do you suggest should be the right way to do it?

Comment: According to a random resource I found out there, the object should be a parameter of `withCss` function. https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/next-css-and-exportpathmap-in-one-next-config-js-file~c6ddf137-635c-4fda-83e5-9ceeb96e4350?m=MTU1MTAwNTQyMDExMA==

Answer (score 0):

you should put everything into `withCss`

```
module.exports = withCss({
    exportPathMap: function() {
        return {
            '/': { page: '/' },
            '/about': { page: '/about' },
            '/abc': { page: '/abc' },
            '/other': { page: '/other' },
            '/there': { page: '/there' },
            '/sample': { page: '/sample' },
            '/details': { page: '/details' },
        };
    },
});
```